# infinitesimal generator of a Markov process

Tags: markov-process, exponential-distribution

> **Problem:** There are $n$ identical components in a system that operate independently. When a component fails, it undergoes repair, and after repair is placed back into the system. Assume that for a component the operating times between successive failures are i.i.d. exponential with mean $\frac{1}{\lambda}$, and that these are independent of the successive repair times, which are i.i.d. exponential with mean $\frac{1}{\mu}$. The state of the system is the number of components in operation. Determine the infinitesimal generator of this Markov process.

I try to find the transition probabilities $\mathbb{P}(X_t = j|X_s = i)$. First, consider the cases when $i>j$, which means more components failed in the time period than repaired. Let $k$ be the number of components that fails during $[s,t]$, then the rest of $i$ components didn't fail. Also $k - (i-j)$ components were repaired. I got this equation:
$$
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X_t = j|X_s = i) &= p_{ij}(t-s)\\ &=\sum_{k=i-j}^{i}{i \choose k}(\int_0^{t-s}\lambda e^{-\lambda u}du)^k(\int_{t-s}^{\infty}\lambda e^{-\lambda u}du)^{i-k}{n-i+k \choose n-j}(\int_0^{t-s}\mu e^{-\mu u}du)^{k-(i-j)}(\int_{t-s}^{\infty}\mu e^{-\mu u}du)^{n-j}
\end{align}
$$
But this doesn't seem right, because then I get $q_{ij} = p'_{ij}(0) = 0$.
Help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In this problem it seems most reasonable to consider state transitions to be the failure or repair of a component. In this case the state space is $\{0,1,\ldots, n\}$ and the infinitesimal generator would have superdiagonal entries (starting from $(0,1)$) $\frac n\mu,\frac{n-2}\mu,\ldots,\frac1\mu$, subdiagonal entries (starting from $(1,0)$) $\frac1\lambda,\frac2\lambda,\ldots,\frac n\lambda$, and diagonal entries as according to make the rows sum to zero.

So for example if $n=4$ then
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 -\frac{4}{\mu } & \frac{4}{\mu } & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 \frac{1}{\lambda } & -\left(\frac{1}{\lambda }+\frac{3}{\mu }\right) & \frac{3}{\mu } & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & \frac{2}{\lambda } & -\left(\frac{2}{\lambda }+\frac{2}{\mu }\right) & \frac{2}{\mu } & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & \frac{3}{\lambda } & -\left(\frac{3}{\lambda }+\frac{1}{\mu }\right) & \frac{1}{\mu } \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{4}{\lambda } & -\frac{4}{\lambda } \\
\end{array}
\right).
$$

Comment: The second and third conditions you wrote on $(i,j)$ don't mean what you want them to mean. Also, shouldn't components in general fail faster if there are more of them in independent operation? Same for repairs.

Comment: Ah, indeed I will correct this.